# functional testing, windows store app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, functional-testing

How exactly do I need to run the activation tool for functional testing windows metro application? I am using Visual studio 2012 as the testing platform. I am new to the field, could someone please explain me the process step by step? I found a code in C# for the automation but haven't been able to run it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tool to automate a Metro application check [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/windows.html).

Stating from version 6.0 a number of features in RIATest are specifically targeted at Metro style application automation, particularly:

- Ability to stay on top of Metro UI to allow you to simultaneously see your Metro application and RIATest IDE and minimize switching from Desktop to Metro screens when automating a Metro application.
- Recording of actions performed on native Windows GUI elements (including Metro GUI). The recorder analyses your script code and reuses your variable names to generate cleaner recorded scripts similar to how you would hand-code an automation script.
- Seamless workaround for [bugs like this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779279/ui-automation-tree-is-broken-for-windows-8-store-application) in Windows UI Automation implementation in Metro UI.

*Disclaimer: I work for Cogitek, the RIATest company.*